# there's a better way to recover the parameters of a func inside a IF without calling twice?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I have a piece of code, it's working, but it takes to long to execute, i have made this simplified version to ilustrate my problem

```
def teste(x):
    if x > 1:
        return x, "whatever", {'foo':'bar'}
    else:
        return False

x = 2

if teste(x):
    a,b,c = teste(x)
else:
    print("false")
```

there's a better way to do this?
i have tried

```
if(a,b,c = teste(x)):
```

but i got a syntax error

Comment: x is a variable, it wont be equal to 2 everytime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to unpack when calling the function.

Store the result in a variable then test

```
result = teste(x)
if result:
    a,b,c = result
else:
    print("false")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `x <= 1` to return `False` as you have it in `teste(x)`, then you could just duck type it.

```
x = 2
try:
    a, b, c = teste(x)
except TypeError:
    print('false')
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want the behavior to be. If you want to initialize `a, b, c` regardless, you can do

```py
a, b, c = teste(x) or None, None, None
```

And then check if, say, `a is None`.